# AutoMapper custom conversion

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to define custom conversion logic with AutoMapper, such as I have the source type that contains two properties "NameFr" and "NameNl" which are strings and I'd like to create some kind of custom converter to automatically converts these two properties in one object with a `Fr` and `Nl` properties.

So basically, I would have this source type:

```
class Source {
   public string NameFr { get; set; }
   public string NameNl { get; set; }
}
```

This utility class:

```
class LocalizedString {
   public string Fr { get; set; }
   public string Nl { get; set; }
}
```

And this destination type:

```
class Destination {
   public LocalizedString Name { get; set; }
}
```

So basically, the idea would be to be able to write some custom conversion logic to indicate that if the destination property is a `LocalizedString` called "Foo", it should be a new object with its `Fr` property set to the value of `FooFr` and the `Nl` property set to `FooNl` of the source object.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example with sample data to show your expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

```
    c.CreateMap<Destination, Source>().ReverseMap();
```

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html